# compartir session en expressjs

Tags: express

quiero compartir la session que creo en el server a un router

**en el server: app.js**

```
var routesEvaluacion = require('./routes/evaluacion');
app.use('/evaluacion', routesEvaluacion);
...
app.use(session({
    secret: 'administrador',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))
app.post('/consultas', function (req, res) {

    if (req.body.nombre === "student" && req.body.pass === "student") {
        req.session.nombre = 'student';
        res.redirect('/listaEvaluaciones');
    }

});
```

**y necesito la session en el router evaluacion.js**

```
router.get('/autenticacion/:id',function (req, res) {
 // necesito la session **req.session.nombre**
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Crédito a robertklep por su [respuesta en Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39796445/3695983).

Una vez que montas un router en una aplicación en Express, cualquier declaración de middleware que ocurra después en la app, no será llamada en las peticiones que tengan como objetivo ese router.

Por ejemplo, si haces esto:

```
app.use(router);
app.use(session(...));
```

Entonces `session` no estará disponible en `router`. Pero sí lo estará si cambias el orden:

```
app.use(session(...));
app.use(router);
```

---

Debes montar el router (en tu caso `evaluacion`) después de definir la session y no antes para solucionar el problema:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'administrador',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))
...
app.use('/evaluacion', routesEvaluacion);
...
```